# French in the Indian version of the Samsung Note 4

Tags: samsung

I have the Indian version of the Samsung Note 4. I want to change the language to French, but I don't see French or German in the list of possibilities. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [MoreLocale 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale&hl=en) from the Play Store.

Taken from the app page:

> You can select more locales via this app.
>   If your locale doesn't appear, please use custom locale function in menu.